# How to parse an email in Python without closing the file?

Tags: python, email, python-3.x, python-3.4

I still need to use the file after it is parsed as en email but the email parser is closing it.

What can I do?

thanks

```
(venv3.4)ubuntu@core01:~/tmp$ cat tmp.eml
From: Example Person <example.person@example.org>
To: another.person@example.org
Subject: test2
Date: Sun, 2 Mar 2014 15:42:27 +1100

Hello

(venv3.4)ubuntu@core01:~/tmp$ cat tmp.py

from email.parser import BytesParser, BytesHeaderParser
from email import policy

f = open('tmp.eml', 'rb')

def parsefromfile(f, headersonly=None):
    f.seek(0)
    if headersonly:
        msg = BytesHeaderParser(policy=policy.default).parse(f)
    else:
        msg = BytesParser(policy=policy.default).parse(f)
    print(msg)
    print(msg.get('date', None))
    f.seek(0)
    print(f.read())

parsefromfile(f)


(venv3.4)ubuntu@core01:~/tmp$ python tmp.py

From: Example Person <example.person@example.org>
To: another.person@example.org
Subject: test2
Date: Sun, 2 Mar 2014 15:42:27 +1100

Hello


Sun, 02 Mar 2014 15:42:27 +1100
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 17, in <module>
    parsefromfile(f)
  File "tmp.py", line 14, in parsefromfile
    f.seek(0)
ValueError: seek of closed file
```

Comment: This is quite strange because the source code for `parse` is pretty simple http://hg.python.org/releasing/3.4/file/77082b818676/Lib/email/parser.py and it doesn't do anything with `fp` except `read`.

Comment: @luk32 are you saying it doesn't close the file? How can the file be closed if the parser doesn't close it?

Comment: I dunno, check the code it's under 10 lines only, really simple. It creates a parser object, and reads data from a file pointer, but it doesn't close it. I also think you can pass `headersonly` as the argument and spare this one `if`.

Comment: Um... there is inconsistency in the behaviour IMO. Because if you open file in the text mode and use `Parser` in the text mode it doesn't close the file. But `BytesParser` overwrites `fp` with `TextIOWrapper` and it somewhat closes it. I think it can be considered a bug.

Comment: A somewhat closed file is certainly not a good thing.

Comment: It would be fine if it were documented and behaved consistently IMO =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the parsebytes function instead. Get the string content of the file using .read() and pass that in, then continue operating on your file object.

Comment: Yes this makes sense don't know why I didn't think of it.  Does anyone know why the parser closes the file?

Answer (score 1):

So, this was actually a bug in python - http://bugs.python.org/issue21476. The fix is set to go live, I think, on python3.5 and next minor version of python 3.4 i.e. 3.4.2. The file descriptor should not get closed, and OPs code should be valid for those versions.

Comment: Nice one on the follow up.